# House vs. home in other languages

Tags: words, examples

In American English, one's *house* refers to his or her physical dwelling, while one's *home* is so much more. A home is a building, a city, even a country where one feels he or she belongs most. It's a very powerful word describing a very powerful and innately human concept.

But it's also a concept that doesn't translate well. I've been working with Google Translate (ugh) and for most languages of interest I really can't find a word that represents the idea of *home* properly. Is it uncommon for this concept to have an associated term? Is this simply representative of a feeling firmly American in origin? Are there any good examples of this idea in other languages?

Comment: Not sure why specifically "American" -- British and other English varieties show the same distinction.

Comment: English lacks a basic word to denote one's younger sibling, but I'm sure even English speakers feel an innate love, protective instinct, and mild annoyance when looking at one's brother who is five years younger, quite distinct from how one feels about another brother five years older.  You can't assume people feel something differently just because they divide words' meanings at a different boundary.

Comment: You should give example sentences or explicitly list the senses.  Both of these words are overloaded in English too.

Comment: @jick The Sapir-Whorf Hypothesis, supported by quite a bit of evidence, states that language strongly influences perception of the world in just such a way that presence or absence of terms could certainly indicate presence or absence of the experiences corresponding to said terms. By the way, English _does_ have a word for a younger sibling, a compound noun: _little brother_ and _little sister_

Comment: @TheEnvironmentalist The strong version of the [Sapir-Whorf hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_relativity), as famous and interesting as it is, has been mostly discredited, by years and years of repeated psycholinguistic research. The strong version only holds in science fiction (like in the movie Arrival). If the strong version held, translation and learning another language would be impossible.

Comment: @TheEnvironmentalist As to the weak version, sure that is trivial, having a vocabulary for sailing implements on a ship makes it easier to work there or that one tribe in Australia can tell direction better in an underground maze because their language has no words for left and right but does for north and south so they have constant practice keeping track of direction. Other than the trivial or the arcane, there really isn't that much effect of language on thought.

Answer (score 6):

Many Romance languages have this distinction. In addition to French *foyer* noted by @Philippe, there are the Romance cognates Spanish *hogar*, Galician *fogar*, with the meaning of "home", from Vulgar Latin *focarium*, ultimately derived from the Latin *focus* "hearth". These are distinct from *casa* "house" (< L.)

Notably, Portuguese has *[lar](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lar#Portuguese)* for "home", derived from the Etruscan (via Latin) *LAR*.

Comment: I always thought *lar* sounded funny, but didn't look into it & never imagined it was Etruscan. Cool!

Comment: However, *lar* is definitely non-colloquial, almost an eruditism. Most Portuguese-speaking people say that they *vão para casa* when they mean they are going home.

Comment: I'm a native Brazilian Portuguese speaker and, while I feel it as literary, I'd never call it an eruditism (like, say, using the classical second-person plural).  While I definitely *vou pra casa* after work, if I'm talking about my "home sweet home" it will be a *lar doce lar*, if I'm saying that "our mind is our home" it will be *nossa mente é nosso lar*, if I'm talking about children who make the streets into their home they'll be *crianças que fazem da rua seu lar*, etc. These sound much less pompous to me than what's usually considered "eruditism", like *ígneo* for "fiery" etc.

Comment: (cont.) *Lar* ranks #1676 in the top 5000 most frequently spoken words from [opensubtitles](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Frequency_lists/BrazilianPortuguese_wordlist); much less common than *casa* (#96), of course, but still comfortably within the core 2k, which is far from an eruditism in my mind (it's above *chuva* "rain", *besteira* "nonsense" or *moradia* "habitation", for example).

Comment: I'm native too, and I do agree it's not an eruditism, but I'm sure chuva and besteira should be above it. I don't know about moradia, probably should be above it too.

Comment: @leoboiko - I don't think it is an eruditism, just it is almost like one, and definitely not colloquial. It is popular in "frases feitas" such as "*lar doce lar*", but quite rarely used otherwise (for instance, most people would say/write "*crianças que moram na rua*" rather than "*crianças que fazem da rua seu lar*").

Comment: @SavioSG - It is indeed weird that is is placed above *chuva* or *besteira*. Those are words I speak and hear everyday, whenever it rains (or, living in Brasília, whenever we miss rain too much) and whenever someone does or says anything less than clever. *Lar* is something I certainly do not hear in common conversation, except in either a sententious or mocking context.

Comment: Even the exact sentence *fazem da rua seu lar* can be easily found in the wild ([1](https://books.google.de/books?id=w1q_0hAckwYC&pg=PA734&lpg=PA734&dq=%22fazem+da+rua+seu+lar%22), [2](http://m.portalangop.co.ao/angola/pt_pt/mobile/noticias/sociedade/2007/7/35/Governante-pede-contribuicao-sociedade-melhoria-situacao-crianca,a66bbd49-b40a-4ab7-83a7-a73fd87dd183.html?version=mobile), [3](http://vozerio.org.br/Moradores-de-rua-quem-sao-eles-e)…)

Comment: The Brazilian Portuguese web-dialect corpus at corpusdoportugues.org has 30297 hits for *lar*, vs. 10949 for *besteira* and 48590 for *chuva*.  So it's definitely within the same order of magnitude as such common words, in this corpus as well as the movie-based one.

Comment: At least in Brazil we use "lar" exclusively when denoting where we live. In other situations - as when a team is playing at his own stadium - we use "casa". So the word "lar" is not a 1..1 translation for "home".

Answer (score 4):

In French, the terms "*foyer*" and "*chez soi*" express the concept of *home* with a strong nuance of "one's family' for the first (*foyer* is originally the fireplace, and by extension the hearth), while the latter is "one's own place" and therefore the place where one feels they belong. In some contexts, the word *demeure* also shares some of the nuances of the English word *home*.

In Japanese, there are terms like *uchi* (内) or *wagaya* (我が家) that can partially cover the concept (the first is broader in that in can cover any in-group to which the speaker belongs, depending on the context, while the second is my/our home/household/family), but their use is more restricted. There is also the term "ibasho" (居場所) which refers to the place where one belongs.

I don't speak any other languages fluently enough to provide other examples, but I think you'll find that, as with most terms, and especially those describing abstract concepts, you won't find a one-to-one correspondence where other languages will have only one word corresponding exactly to *home*. Rather, as with my French and Japanese examples above, you'll find that although the concept (or, rather, set of concepts) is quite common, how it is expressed will vary (sometimes considerably) from one language to the next.

Answer (score 4):

In Russian, both *house* and *home* are the same, дом [dom], but in Ukrainian (which is closely related to Russian) the same word, дім [dʲim] (gen. sg. дому ['dɔmu]) is usually used to mean *home*, while *house* is called by different other words, like хата ['xata], будинок [bu'dɪnɔk], кам’яниця ['kamjanɪtsʲa] (rare), etc. I wrote "usually", because дім [dʲim] is sometimes used to mean *house*, too.

Answer (score 2):

In Russian there are adverbs дома and домой similar to English adverb "home" (as in go home, at home)

Я дома = I am at home (adverb)

Я в доме = I am in the house (noun)

Я иду домой = I am going home (adverb)

Я иду в дом = I am going into the house (noun)

Answer (score 1):

In Hindi घर (ghar) can mean both "house" and "home". मकान (maka:n) only means "house" but is a pretty common word nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to *(o)uchi*, Japanese has *furusato* which is translated to `hometown`. With nuisance, however `the area in which one grew up` is more accurate than the mapped borders of the town.

Japanese words often carry emotional weight: *(o)uchi* has a feeling of belonging, *wagaya* has a feeling of family and any associated feelings thereof, and *furusato* has a heavy feeling of nostalgia.

Answer (score 1):

In Czech and Slovak they are two different words (unlike Russian where дом can be both).

Czech:

- dům - house
- domov - home
- doma, domů - at home, (towards) home

originates in Proto-Slavic [*dȏmъ](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/dom%D1%8A) - house, home

Answer (score 0):

In Chinese:

家 means home, including but not limited to the physical dwelling, and family members. This word can means a lot and makes people feel warm emotionally. I think this is the word best matches home in English.

Besides, there are some related words:

- 家庭 means family.
- 家乡 means hometown.
- 房子/房屋/住宅 means house.

Answer (score 0):

In **Swedish** and the Scandinavian languages in general we have the exact same distinction as in English.

**House** -> **Hus** *(same in Norwegian and Danish)*
**Home** -> **Hem** *(Hjem in Norwegian and Danish)*

*(If someone has the phonetics they may add them)*

Comment: _Hem_ is not the same in Norwegian and Danish; it’s _hjem_ or _heim_ in Norwegian (both in Bokmål, only _heim_ in Nynorsk) and _hjem_ in Danish.

Answer (score 0):

My mother tongue is Saurashtra, which developed from Gujarati but has had lots of Marathi and Dravidian influence. I did also notice that apart from Saurashtra and English, pretty much no other language has this distinction between a building where one can live, and the place where one does live.

House - Ghér घेर
Home - Ghomma घोंम